# Are calemondin leaves edible?

Tags: fruit, citrus

I have a little bush which lost quite a few leaves due to overwatering. They are healthy looking and fragment. 
I wonder if I can use them in a similar way to kaffir lime leaves? I couldn't find much info re: toxicity, but lemon leaves are used in some regions to impart flavour .

Answer (score 1):

This is Texas A&M University's description of calemondin:
http://aggie-horticulture.tamu.edu/patiocitrus/Calamondin.html

In it, they seem to indicate that the leaves are not toxic:

> The distilled oil of the leaves serves as a carminative with more
>   potency than peppermint oil.

However, they list just about every use of the tree and its fruit, from marmalades to hair conditioner, and that's the only mention of the leaves.  Because that's the only usage mentioned, I would suspect that even if the leaves are not toxic, they're not suited for flavoring anything.

I hope that's at least a little helpful.

Comment: thank you that's useful. The leaves are bitter and fragrant and I imagine they could be used to give a distinct note to stews and curries.

Comment: Their horticulture department has all kinds of good information and references.  Here's another detailing commonly found poisonous plants or plant parts: http://aggie-horticulture.tamu.edu/earthkind/landscape/poisonous-plants-resources/common-poisonous-plants-and-plant-parts/